# launching appium server through python script gives error

Tags: shell, python-2.7, subprocess, appium, python-appium

I am launching appium server through terminal by command `appium` and in another terminal I run my test suite `python test.py` This works fine.
But if launch through python script I get error between 2 tests

```
def setup(self):
        subprocess.Popen('appium', shell=False)
        time.sleep(5)
        desired_caps = dict()
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '6.0'
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Android Emulator'
        desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath('test.apk')
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
        return self.driver
```

error: `Couldn't start Appium REST http interface listener. Requested port is already in use. Please make sure there's no other instance of Appium running already.`

**The error has no effect tests still pass**

I tried adding killall node in teardown

```
def tearDown(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
    self.driver.quit()
    subprocess.Popen('killall node', shell=False)
```

but it gives me error

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I get rid of error and stop appium server?

Setup is called through launch app -> click some buttons -> call teardown through close app

Comment: I don't know what is `appium` but you could `self.appium = subprocess.Popen('appium'); assert self.appium.poll() is None # running` and add `self.appium.terminate(); self.appium.wait();` in `tearDown()` or use some other method to stop `appium` process.

Comment: self.appium.terminate() worked !